# Платежные системы и API

Tags: платежи, api, php

Доброе время суток. Задался таким вопросом, как баланс пользователя на сайте, с возможностью ввода и вывода денег. Как такое можно реализовать? Сейчас больше присматриваюсь к API платежных систем. Хочется услышать ваше мнение о данной реализации. Пока что кроме как пополнения баланса ничего не нашел. Т.е. проблема в выводе средств таким же, как и их ввод. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от страны проживания пользователя. Есть много партнёрских систем которые предлагают разные варианты пополнения счёта. Пилить самому будет трудно. Также стоит учесть налоговое законодательство своей страны и стран в которых проживают пользователи которым выплаты будут делаться.

Answer (score 0):

смски - очень большая комиссия, робокасса и киви - для нормальной работы надо быть юр лицом и уже готовый функционал, с физ лицами они конечно тоже работают, но с рядом ограничений.
яндекс и вебмани не рассматриваю - так в моей стране не получили распространения.

Answer (score 0):

Для ввода Robokassa или DigiSeller.
Для вывода (пользователям) использовать интерфейсы и api систем в которую происходит вывод.

Ну а если пополнение будут приниматься лишь с WebMoney то Merchant в помощь.